# IPython inconsistent behavior in line continuation of raw string

Tags: python, ipython

CPython and IPython shell seemingly have subtly different interpretations about the line continuation of raw string. The behaviors are very easy to demonstrate.

- Example 1: Line continuation of raw string.

CPython result:

```
>>> r'abc\
... def'
'abc\\\ndef'
```

IPython shell result:

```
In [1]: r'abc\
   ...: def'
Out[1]: 'abcdef'
```

- Example 2: Escaped line continuation of raw string.

CPython result (press `<Enter>` right after `\\`):

```
>>> r'abc\\
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    r'abc\\
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

IPython shell result:

```
In [1]: r'abc\\
   ...: def'
Out[1]: 'abc\\def'
```

It should be clear the CPython result is correct in both cases, as it conforms the part of [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> [...] Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is
>   interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a
>   line continuation.

and the next paragraph:

> [...] Backslashes can be escaped with a preceding backslash; however, both
>   remain in the string.

Is this a bug in IPython shell?

Related sysinfo: IPython 2.4.1, tested with both CPython 2.7.10 and 3.4.2, on Fedora 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been raised on `IPython` github

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5828

It is recognized as a bug, but doesn't seem to have a high priority.  It only affects raw strings.

I can't think of a situation where it would bother me.  Where would I need `'abc\\\ndef'`?